# Flask as proxy doesn't work when deployed to tornado

Tags: python, proxy, flask, tornado

I wrote a flask app as kind of a proxy, to analyse the data passing through it and provide a web page where I get the result. All seems to went well when using the default development server that comes with flask, say using:

```
app.run()
```

But when I tried to deploy the app to a server, for example tornado or wsgiref.simple_server in Python standard library using:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from app import app

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

or

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from app import app

httpd = make_server('', 5000, app)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This two ways result in getting 404 error on requests got 200 OK previously.

The requests my app gets, since it serves as a proxy, are with absolute urls in the request lines like `POST http://example.com/test HTTP/1.1`. When I'm using the development server, this request is handled by the function registered under `/test` normally, something like:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_test():
    ...
```

and the `request.url`, as I checked, is `http://example.com/test`.

When using the other two ways, the request is handled by the error handler with code 404, and the `handle_test()` function is never invoked. The `request.url`, which seems to cause the problem, is `http://example.com/http://example.com/test`, definitely not what I want.

So I want to know:

1. What changed the url to the wrong one, and when did this happen.
2. Why the app behaves differently on default development server and servers like tornado.
3. Of course, how to get rid of this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado does not currently support proxy-style requests; see https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1036

Tornado's WSGIContainer is also a poor choice for proxies because of its single-threaded concurrency model (see http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer). Even if the aforementioned bug were fixed, your proxy would perform poorly. I recommend either using a multithreaded WSGI server (like gunicorn or uwsgi, although I don't know whether they support proxy-style requests) or rewriting the proxy as a native Tornado app (without flask) to take advantage of asynchronous features.